# How show images in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to show all images that are in a particular folder, I have the folder path but I do not see how the number of images there are inside and how show all. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your files are inside public or a subfolder of it, this is is a way:

```
foreach (File::allFiles(public_path().'/assets/img/') as $file)
{
    $filename = $file->getRelativePathName();

    echo HTML::image('public/assets/img/'.$filename, $filename);
}
```

This is a router you can use to test it:

```
Route::any('images', function() {

    $images = '';

    foreach (File::allFiles(public_path() . '/assets/img/') as $file) 
    {
        $filename = $file->getRelativePathName();

        $images .= HTML::image('public/assets/img/'.$filename, $filename);
    }

    return "<htm><body>$images</body></htm>";

});
```

Edit the `/assets/img/` to your own and just hit `http://yourserver.dev/images`.